# Need help improving the speed of a select statement

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, inner-join

I have a select statement that is taking too long to run. It's probably because it needs to exclude about 98K records. Here is the scenario. I have two select statements: The first select gives me a list of IdValues. I take these IDValues (about 98K Records) and run them in my second select as an exclusion.

Query One

```
Select IdValue,IDName,IDCreatedby from Table1
Inner Join Table2 ON Table1Id.Table2Id
WHERE IdName = 'Acquisition'
```

Let's say the result set of the first query is as follows: IdValue1, IdValue2, IdValue3...
So I take these values and tell my query to exclude these values.

Query Two

```
Select FName, MI, LName, and Dateofpurchase from Table3
inner join Table4 on Table3.Id=Table4.id
where PurchaseType = 'Holiday'
and IdValue not in ('IdValue1','IdValue2','IdValue3') (98K records for these Values)
```

Query Two is taking a lot of time to run, and I would like to see if I can make this query faster. Currently, I am copying the IdValues from query one, putting it into an excel file, then after I add '', I include it in the second query. This takes so much time, let alone the query's execution time.

Any help I can get is appreciated.

Comment: please show the structure of the involved tables. Now your queries contain syntax errors

Comment: in the first query which of the tables have idvalue?

Answer (score 0):

What you do is a left join and then only take the null values.  This is faster than having to store all 98k values and if your indexes are set up well it will be very fast.  something like this -- note it was hard to tell what fields went to what alias so I made some guesses.

```
Select FName, MI, LName, Dateofpurchase 
from Table3
join Table4 on Table3.Id=Table4.id
left join (
  Select IdValue
  from Table1
  Join Table2 ON Table1Id.Table2Id = table2.id
  WHERE IdName = 'Acquisition'
) x on x.idValue = table3.idvalue
where PurchaseType = 'Holiday'
  and x.IdValue is null
```

This can be optimized -- for example if table1 has the idvalue returned by in x.idvalue then you don't even need a sub-query

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS is something you should get familiar with. It performs better than NOT IN, as NOT IN is basically a series of:

```
 THIS OR THAT OR THIS OR THAT etc etc etc
```

I also left you some handy dandy tips for you. These tips point out something that is very important, especially for people who have to look at your code and try and figure things out.

```
SELECT 
    FName  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
    , MI  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
    , LName  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
    , Dateofpurchase  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
FROM 
    Table3  -- alias your tables 
    INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.Id = Table4.id  -- alias your tables 
WHERE 
    PurchaseType = 'Holiday'  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            Select 
                IdValue  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
            from 
                Table1   -- alias your tables 
                Inner Join Table2 ON Table1Id.Table2Id   -- alias your tables 
            WHERE 
                IdName = 'Acquisition'  -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
                AND IdValue = IdValue   -- all columns should have the proper table qualifier/alias
        )
```

Comment: nb -- NOT EXISTS will compile to the same code as a LEFT JOIN and check for nulls (as my answer) but is not as versatile .  But I like your comments about other problems with the code -- which there were many.

Comment: @Hogan that is absolutely not true. JOINs will cause unnecessary amounts of reads, especially in larger data sets. NOT EXISTS is most often way more performant than JOINs. So much so that it is common feedback in code reviews and optimization questions. If you're curious about this and want to learn something, mock up some code to dump 3 million records in 2 different  temp tables, index them appropriately , make sure to include SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON, and then run the two different queries.  You will see that NOT EXISTS and JOIN 100% do not behave the same.

Comment: you probably are already familiar with Erik Darling, one of my favorite sql bloggers, but he has a pretty decent recent read on the topic. https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/why-not-exists-makes-more-sense-than-left-joins/

Comment: This link is a very light review of the topic but you make a good point  that a platform may compile them different.  However, the results are greatly impacted by the size of the data sets and the db platform.  A platform that has partitions and can leverage them in parallel for example will perform much better with joins where the data transfer times would impact the total performance.